# Is there a nuance between 'It had gone' and 'It was gone'

Tags: grammar

I looked for my car in the parking lot, but it was gone.

I looked for my car in the parking lot, but it had gone.

Answer (score 1):

"Gone" is both a verb (the past participle of *to go*) and an adjective (meaning not there anymore, missing etc).

"Had" is an auxiliary verb, so "had gone" suggests that the car has gone somewhere, and that action of 'going' has occurred in the past.

"Was" is a form of the verb *to be*, so "was gone" just describes the current status, that it isn't there. It could be interchangeable with other adjectives such as "it was *missing*".

The overall meaning is the same - the car isn't there. But the nuance is that "had gone" suggests you know it has been taken, whereas "was gone" suggests you don't know how or why it isn't there.